# How to get RSA parameters (exponent and mod) from PrivateKey in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, rsa, private-key, exponent

I'm trying to get the RSA Private Parameters (D,e) from a PrivateKey in Objective-C

Until now I've been capable of read a .p12 file and get its PublicKey:

```
{
- (NSData *)getPublicKeyExp:(NSData*) bitsPublicKey
{
    NSData* pk = bitsPublicKey;
    if (pk == NULL) return NULL;

    int iterator = 0;

    iterator++; // TYPE - bit stream - mod + exp
    [self derEncodingGetSizeFrom:pk at:&iterator]; // Total size

    iterator++; // TYPE - bit stream mod
    int mod_size = [self derEncodingGetSizeFrom:pk at:&iterator];
    iterator += mod_size;

    iterator++; // TYPE - bit stream exp
    int exp_size = [self derEncodingGetSizeFrom:pk at:&iterator];

    return [pk subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(iterator, exp_size)];
}

- (NSData *)getPublicKeyMod:(NSData*) bitsPublicKey
{
    NSData* pk = bitsPublicKey;
    if (pk == NULL) return NULL;

    int iterator = 0;

    iterator++; // TYPE - bit stream - mod + exp
    [self derEncodingGetSizeFrom:pk at:&iterator]; // Total size

    iterator++; // TYPE - bit stream mod
    int mod_size = [self derEncodingGetSizeFrom:pk at:&iterator];

    return [pk subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(iterator, mod_size)];
}

- (int)derEncodingGetSizeFrom:(NSData*)buf at:(int*)iterator
{
    const uint8_t* data = [buf bytes];
    int itr = *iterator;
    int num_bytes = 1;
    int ret = 0;

    if (data[itr] > 0x80) {
        num_bytes = data[itr] - 0x80;
        itr++;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < num_bytes; i++) ret = (ret * 0x100) + data[itr + i];

    *iterator = itr + num_bytes;
    return ret;
}
}
```

I get Public exponent and modulo.

My problem became when I try to do the same with a Private Key in the same .p12 format. I use same functions before but the parameters aren't valid. I've been broken my brain on this problem. Could you give me some clue please?

Thanks in advance